# Python Cryptography lib not found by AWS lambda function while using DocuSign-esign

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use DocuSign-esign python sdk on AWS but get the following error:

Err: Algorithm 'RS256' could not be found. Do you have cryptography installed?

Even though I have all the dependencies installed/uploaded onto a layer.

So far I've tried:

1. Using Pycryptodome instead of Cryptography
2. Using the Linux distribution of Cryptography

These were the two solutions I found online, and neither worked.